# Fortune wheel slicing

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials, modifiers

I am trying to make a fortune wheel which I can use in Unity.

A friend of mine said he needed the parts which have money written on them sliced.

How can I slice/make each of these parts separate?

I basically need to make each of the parts that have money written on them a slice of their own.

Thank you in advance, I am pretty new to Blender so I still have a lot to learn.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a 32 (or more) vertex circle, *Fill Type > Triangle Fan*:

[image]

Rip it in 8 parts with <kbd>V</kbd>:

[image]

Extrude up:

[image]

You have now 8 slices, you can project your image on them, separate them in 8 distinct objects if necessary, etc...

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Use the knife project operator.

Take your object you want to slice.

Then add another circle mesh that has as many verts as you want slices.
Rotate it into position, push `F` to fill it, and then `F3` to search for `Poke faces` to get it separated into smaller triangles.

[image]

[image]

You can also do all of this when you add the circle in the first place, in the Add Circle options. It's useful to know this method too.

[image]

Then go into edit mode and search for "Delete Faces Only" which does just that, leaving only edges behind.

[image]

Here's where it gets tricky.

1. Select the object you want sliced.
2. In edit mode select the geo you want to receive the cut.

[image]

3. Then `CTRL + Click` the "cutter mesh" while still in edit mode on the main object. You'll see it turn red.

[image]

4. Then swing into front orthographic view, `Numpad-1`.
5. Search for "Knife Project" and shoot.
6. If you did everything right you should have exactly what you're looking for. The edges of the cutter mesh shoot out onto the surface of the main object. Pretty nifty.

[image]

It's okay if you have to try like 6 times. Honestly i think I can count the amount of times I've done it 100% correct on the first go on one hand.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts i really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

with this nodes setup in Geometry nodes you can get it procedurally and with text (hopefully someone has a better text solution than i have - mine is pretty bad...but a beginning ;))

[image]

[image]

Comment: oh man, a bit too simple, don't you have a crazier solution?  ^^

Comment: Of course - just working on it. Will be released in 2029…

Comment: Haha man you love Blender a little too much, thank you so much.

Comment: yes, that's true ;)